# cardview rows with multimple items

Tags: android

I have a `Recyclerview` with `Cardviews` as rows.Each `Cardview` will be created based on a date.For example one cardview for 4/6/16 one for 5/6/16 etc.
Each `Cardview` in it's turn can have multiple `LinearLayouts` as rows based on data from a List.

How can i achieve this?I've thought of using a Recycler for each CardView, but maybe there is a simpler solution?

I hope i was understood!

[image]

Comment: Return view based on viewtype like this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6414107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use nested recycler view or you can have list view in your recycler view row.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Inflate your row layout with list/nested recycler view here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //set your list/nested recycler view adaptor here based on data at 'postion'.
        holder.listView.setadaptor(new ListViewAdaptor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.lenght();
    }
}

public class ListViewAdaptor extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.length()
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //listview row layout inflation goes here
    }
}
```

}